# SQL check user access in one command?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to check if a user has access to one document, in one command in SQL. I try to avoid putting much PHP in the checkAccess() function.

I have a username and a document id.

Say username is `user1` and document id is `24`.

These are my tables:

```
mysql> describe permissions;
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| wfId   | char(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| docId  | char(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userId | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe users;
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| login    | char(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password | char(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe documents;
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | char(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| wfid    | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| docid   | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created | datetime  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated | datetime  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And this is the query I am building:

```
mysql> select u.login, d.id, d.wfid, d.docid, p.wfId, p.docId, p.userId
from permissions p, documents d inner join users u
ON (u.login = "user1" AND d.id = 24 AND p.docId=d.docid AND p.wfId=d.wfid);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'p.docId' in 'on clause'
```

But p.wfId is declared previously. Any help on how could I do it better or what is the error in my sentence?

My objective is that one result is returned, then access is granted. If query result is empty set, then access is denied.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.login, d.id, d.wfid, d.docid, p.wfId, p.docId, p.userId
FROM permissions p
JOIN documents d ON p.docId = d.docid AND p.wdId = d.wdid
JOIN users u ON p.userId = u.id
WHERE u.login = "user1" and d.id = 24
```

The error you got was because your `JOIN` clause was only between `documents` and `users`; since `permissions` wasn't being joined, you can't reference `p.docId` in the `ON` clause.

You were also missing a join condition between `users` and `permissions`, so you would have gotten everyone's permissions, not just user1's permissions.

Conditions that just check a single table, rather than a relationship between tables, should be in the `WHERE` clause rather than `ON` (exception: `OUTER JOIN` sometimes need to restrict to a subset of the table being joined with, and this should be done in the `ON` clause).

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
select u.login, d.id, d.wfid, d.docid, p.wfId, p.docId, p.userId
from permissions p
inner join documents d on p.docId=d.docid AND p.wfId=d.wfid
inner join users u ON u.login = "user1" AND d.id = 24
```

Comment: The query is returning rows for every user who has permissions on that doc. Barmar answer works as expected, but thanks for your help and time anyway!